# RecyclerView hides Actionbar when SoftKeyboard is opened

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

I have the following Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container">

    <com.example.SendMessageLayout
        android:id="@+id/chatMessageLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/chatMessageLayout"
        android:background="@color/seperator_line_inpost"
        />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/separator"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycleView"
            style="@style/BeepMeListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/chatMessageLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
            />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

While SendMessageLayout is just a layout with EditText and a Button.
In the old implementation i used plain old ListView, so when i requested focus for the edit text a keyboard would appear, the listview didn't move, and the first item was visible.
But with the RecyclerView everything is pushed up, not only the top item is out of the screen but it the whole layout is on top of the ActionBar.

Here's how it looks...
[image: RecycleView Screenshot]

Comment: I have the same problem.. can someone help?

Comment: hi, any luck figuring this out ?

Comment: could you post the way how you put the actionbar in XML?

Answer (score 5):

Just add a empty scrollview, solved: [RecyclerView hides Actionbar when SoftKeyboard is opened 解决办法](http://drakeet.me/solve-a-stackoverflow-post-recyclerview-hides-actionbar-when-softkeyboard-is-opened)

Like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:context="me.drakeet.seashell.ui.social.PostActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <me.drakeet.seashell.widget.MultiSwipeRefreshLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
            style="@style/BbsBackground"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_reply_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="48dp"/>

        </me.drakeet.seashell.widget.MultiSwipeRefreshLayout>

        <include
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/view_reply"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue and i solved it adding

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

in the activity tag in the manifest