# RecyclerView hides Toolbar and layout when SoftKeyboard is visible

Tags: android, toolbar, android-softkeyboard, android-recyclerview

I've a problem exactly like this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212580/recyclerview-hides-actionbar-when-softkeyboard-is-opened), same situation and same components in layouts.
The only difference is the toolbar, but obviously i'm using appcompat and the behaviour is the same.

Attention, not only the toolbar is hided, but also the upper part of the recyclerview. Is like if the entire fragment is translated up when the softkeyboard is visible.

I'm using a toolbar like this in the main.xml of my activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Tha framelayout is replaced with this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <!--<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />-->

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:pstsIndicatorColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:pstsPaddingMiddle="true"
        android:maxHeight="20dp"
        android:elevation="5dp"
    />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

And inside the view pager i've a tab with this fragment's layout with the recyclerview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewChat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dip"/>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtChatLine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/txt_hint"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button1">
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_send"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When i start to enter text in the edittext the entire layout goes up, the toolbar become invisible (out of the screen) and the recyclerview doesn't scroll, but it's move up.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem and @drakeet solution worked for me:
[RecyclerView hides Actionbar when SoftKeyboard is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212580/recyclerview-hides-actionbar-when-softkeyboard-is-opened)

I included an empty ScrollView between the Toolbar and the RecyclerView and the Toolbar stopped hiding.

```
<include android:id="@+id/app_bar" layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

<!--Empty ScrollView needed so the recyclerview doesn't hide the toolbar-->
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ScrollView>

<view
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"
    android:layout_above="@+id/message_layout"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` from your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Removing  adjustPan is equal to setting adjustUnspecified, which defaults to adjustResize if there is a scrollable element. If this solves your problem, I think you should explicitly write `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` for readers of your code to understand that you really want this value.