# RecyclerView height changes if keyboard is visible

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView in my app. It is part of a fragment (one of several) in an activity. The problem is, when the keyboard is closed it will max out in height and use its internal scroller. When the keyboard opens, the internal scroller turns off and the RecyclerView shows all its children.

The RecyclerView has the option for elements to be added or removed by the end user. In my full implementation, it shows four elements before starting to scroll (with the keyboard closed). When it is the sole fragment, it will max out its height at the screen height.

I've tried setting setting the NestedScrollEnabled to false and while this does stop scrolling, the items it would normally scroll to are no longer accessible. The RecyclerView still changes height depending on keyboard status so the 'hidden' rows become visible when the keyboard is open.

So in short, my RecyclerView is changing its height depending on keyboard visibility. How do I always make it show all its children?

Simplified fragment code that still shows the issue.
Java: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bd46e137a0fb52f79399c11ba5be61bf
XML: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c9bfb3f7577f75befc7aa6d5569311ce

I'm using com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I've encounter an issue using last RecyclerView version.. and even AOSP project don't use the last RecyclerView version.

So ,maybe this will solve your problem, use 23.x.x version and let me know if that resolved the problem :)

Comment: Unfortunately the behavior doesn't change. I tried 23.4, 23.3, and 23.2.

Comment: try some of those solutions http://stackoverflow.com/a/29973249/3187366

Comment: No success either.